# Intellicence load pending forever visual studio Xamarin.Forms

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, intellisense

I am using Visual Studio 2019 latest version 16.7.0

When I create a new Xamarin.Forms Mobile application and Select Android and iOS as target platforms, I have no problem and everything works correctly.
But if I check UWP (Universal Windows) and add it to target platforms, Intellicense will never load.
If I open background tasks, it will show:
 
`Intellicense load pending...`

How should I solve this problem?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

for anyone having the same problem, I found a workaround.

Just create a new project without UWP Target platform, and then add UWP project manually.

for more information about adding UWP project manually, follow [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/windows/installation/).

Comment: You could post it as an answer and mark yourself.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT its not an answer, It's just a workaround. I am still waiting for a soloution to original problem

Comment: Try to uncheck this option:Environment->Preview Features->Load project faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was than visual studio couldn't restore nuget packages and gave timeout error.

I fixed that problem by downloading nuget cli and running

```cs
nuget restore "My Project.sln"
```

after that, I opened my project and the problem was solved

Answer (score 1):

I also had a problem when my build stuck at "Loading IntelliSense" "Load pending", and it was caused by a Nuget package timeout, as [AmirHossein Parsapour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63362898/6910868) correctly pointed out.

I've just canceled the build (Cancel item of the Build menu) and run the build again, so the second time it took just a few seconds for the "Loading IntelliSense" task to complete. This time it was "1/3", "2/3", and finally "3/3" instead of "Load pending" so the build went forward without being stuck at Loading IntelliSense Load pending. Therefore, I didn't even need to close the project and run `nuget restore MyProject.sln`.